# How do I write my Dockerfile to include chromedriver?

Tags: python, docker, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am a newbie to Dockerfile as well as Selenium. I was working on the web scraping using selenium and taking a screenshot. I am trying to dockerize it. This questions of mine seems to be answered in a few questions but it did not solve my error. FYI, I am using a Windows laptop.

The screenshot code works on my local machine but dockerfile seems to be giving me errors.

I am trying to use this version of chromedriver=89.0.4389.82

This is my UPDATED Dockefile,

```
FROM python:3.6

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip install pytest && pip install pytest-mock && pip install pytest-smtp && pip install mock \
pip install schedule && pip install selenium && pip install Selenium-Screenshot && pip install python-dateutil

# For running code
COPY src/screenshotcode.py /

RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y google-chrome-stable
RUN apt-get install libxi6 libgconf-2-4 -y

ENV CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION 2.19
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_DIR /chromedriver
RUN mkdir -p $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR

# Download and install Chromedriver
RUN wget -q --continue -P $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR "http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver_linux64.zip"
RUN unzip $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR/chromedriver* -d $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR

# Put Chromedriver into the PATH
ENV PATH $CHROMEDRIVER_DIR:$PATH

CMD [ "python", "screenshotcode.py" ]
```

My screenshot code,

```
import time
from Screenshot import Screenshot_Clipping
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from email_it import email_it
from environmental_variables import environmental_variables
from error_alert_email import error_alert_email
from selenium import webdriver

def screenshot():

    ob=Screenshot_Clipping.Screenshot()
    
    chrome_options = Options()
    
    chrome_options.add_argument('--start-maximized')    
    chrome_options.add_argument('--start-fullscreen')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
    
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r"C:\Users\me\Documents\Projects\chromedriver.exe")

    print('taking screenshot...')
    img_url=ob.full_Screenshot(driver, path = path, image_name = label)

    print('closing driver...')    
    driver.close()

screenshot()
```

**EDIT: I get the following error**

```
PS C:\Users\me\Documents\Projects\> docker run screenshot
File "scheduler.py", line 16, in <module>
    from screenshot import screenshot
  File "/screenshotcode.py", line 72, in <module>
    screenshot()
  File "/screenshotcode.py", line 32, in screenshot
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.19.346067 (6abd8652f8bc7a1d825962003ac88ec6a37a82f1),platform=Linux 5.4.72-microsoft-standard-WSL2 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 0):

You set in the code the chromedriver to be at:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r"C:\Users\me\Documents\Projects\chromedriver.exe")
```

but in your dockerfile you have it at `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver`
so you need to change your code to

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver")
```

Comment: The error still exists with the change you mentioned.
 File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1364, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver': 'chromedriver'

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Comment: How can i install chromedriver at a specific location??

Comment: I se your update, you just need to update your chromedriver version to 89 to match your browser https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/

Comment: docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "python": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.

Comment: did you put `ENV CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION 89.0.4389.23` instead of `ENV CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION 2.19` ?

Comment: Yes i did. The error is get is: `(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)`